# Alfresco Content transformation from .avi to *.flv using ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, alfresco

I'm trying to transform diferents video formats into .flv in Alfresco
I'm using 'ffmpeg' tool to transform content.
My code:
avi2flv-transform-context.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>
<beans>
    <bean id="transformer.ffmpeg.avi.worker" class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker">
        <property name="mimetypeService">
            <ref bean="mimetypeService" />
        </property>
        <property name="checkCommand">
            <bean name="transformer.ffmpeg.avi.checkcommand" class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec">
                <property name="commandsAndArguments">
                    <map>
                        <entry key=".*">
                            <list>
                                <value>ffmpeg</value>
                                <value>-version</value>
                            </list>
                        </entry>
                    </map>
                </property>
                <property name="errorCodes">
                    <value>1</value>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="transformCommand">
            <bean class="org.alfresco.util.exec.RuntimeExec">
                <property name="commandMap">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="Linux">
                            <value>ffmpeg -i '${target}' ${flv.encoder.params} '${source}'</value>
                        </entry>
                    </map>
                </property>
                <property name="errorCodes">
                    <value>1,2</value>
                </property>
                <property name="waitForCompletion">
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property name="defaultProperties">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="flv.encoder.params">-vcodec flv</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="explicitTransformations">
            <list>
<bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/avi</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-msvideo</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/mpeg</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/mp4</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/mpeg2</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-sgi-movie</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/quicktime</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-ms-asf</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-ms-wmv</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-rad-screenplay</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ExplictTransformationDetails">
                    <property name="sourceMimetype">
                        <value>video/ogg</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="targetMimetype">
                        <value>video/x-flv</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transformer.ffmpeg.avi" class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer" parent="baseContentTransformer">
        <property name="worker">
            <ref bean="transformer.ffmpeg.avi.worker" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

webservice:

```
if(getFile(folderVIDEO, field.filename) == null)
{
                            if(file_test_node=folderVIDEO.createFile(nombrefichero+field.filename)){
                                model.mensajes.push('Se ha creado el fichero '+nombrefichero+field.filename);
                            }else
                                model.mensajes.push('Ha ocurrido un error cuando se intentaba crear el fichero '+nombrefichero+field.filename);
                            file_test_node.properties.content.write(field.content);
                            folderVIDEO = getFolder(search.findNode("workspace://SpacesStore/"+fondoid),nameFolderVIDEO);
                            var action = actions.create("transform"); 
                            // Store the transformed version in the same folder as the source
                            action.parameters["destination-folder"] = file_test_node.parent; 
                            action.parameters["assoc-type"] = "{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}contains"; 
                            action.parameters["assoc-name"] = file_test_node.name + "transformed"; 
                            action.parameters["mime-type"] = "video/x-flv"; 
                            // Execute
                            action.execute(file_test_node);
                        }
```

The error

```
The Web Script /alfresco/s/gcd/fondo has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.

500 Description:     An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Message:    09180016 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 09180029 Failed to execute script '/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)': 09180028 Content conversion failed: reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/18/20/56/65b3457f-c37c-4404-b4b7-9abac30f018d.bin, mimetype=video/x-msvideo, size=1614694, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/18/20/56/e92d00e2-7bd8-4bdd-8d50-b61fe4bac903.bin, mimetype=video/x-flv, size=0, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@745ce55


Exception:  org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException - 09180027 Transformation failed - status indicates an error: Execution result: os: Linux command: [ffmpeg, -i, '/home/inventiaplus/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_target_3008293789769608319.flv', -vcodec flv, '/home/inventiaplus/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_source_5021918644492976031.avi'] succeeded: false exit code: 1 out: err: FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al. configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --e



org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker.transform(RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker.java:272)

org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer.transformInternal(ProxyContentTransformer.java:68)

org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:161)

org.alfresco.repo.content.ContentServiceImpl.transform(ContentServiceImpl.java:555)

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)

net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

org.alfresco.repo.model.ml.MLContentInterceptor.invoke(MLContentInterceptor.java:125)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:44)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceed(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:160)

org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:137)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)

$Proxy42.transform(Unknown Source)

org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.TransformActionExecuter.doTransform(TransformActionExecuter.java:305)

org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.TransformActionExecuter.executeImpl(TransformActionExecuter.java:270)

org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:133)

org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:749)

org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeActionImpl(ActionServiceImpl.java:675)

org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:540)

org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:526)

org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:758)

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)

org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.invoke(AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.java:34)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:44)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceedWithAudit(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:217)

org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceed(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:184)

org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:137)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)

org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)

org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)

$Proxy34.executeAction(Unknown Source)

org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptAction.executeImpl(ScriptAction.java:147)

org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptAction.execute(ScriptAction.java:136)

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155)

org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243)

org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)

org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c59._c9(workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post.js:459)

org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c59.call(workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post.js)

org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)

org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c59._c0(workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post.js:271)

org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c59.call(workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post.js)

org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)

org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)

org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c59.call(workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post.js)

org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c59.exec(workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post.js)

org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:472)

org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:190)

org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:282)

org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)

org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:981)

org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)

org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$2.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:383)

org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:381)

org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:436)

org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:466)

org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:304)

org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:333)

org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:189)

org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118)

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)

org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)

org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)

org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


Exception:  org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException - 09180028 Content conversion failed: reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/18/20/56/65b3457f-c37c-4404-b4b7-9abac30f018d.bin, mimetype=video/x-msvideo, size=1614694, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/18/20/56/e92d00e2-7bd8-4bdd-8d50-b61fe4bac903.bin, mimetype=video/x-flv, size=0, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@745ce55



org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:177)


Exception:  org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException - 09180029 Failed to execute script '/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)': 09180028 Content conversion failed: reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/18/20/56/65b3457f-c37c-4404-b4b7-9abac30f018d.bin, mimetype=video/x-msvideo, size=1614694, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/18/20/56/e92d00e2-7bd8-4bdd-8d50-b61fe4bac903.bin, mimetype=video/x-flv, size=0, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@745ce55



org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:194)


Exception:  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 09180016 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 09180029 Failed to execute script '/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)': 09180028 Content conversion failed: reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/18/20/56/65b3457f-c37c-4404-b4b7-9abac30f018d.bin, mimetype=video/x-msvideo, size=1614694, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/18/20/56/e92d00e2-7bd8-4bdd-8d50-b61fe4bac903.bin, mimetype=video/x-flv, size=0, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@745ce55



org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:758)


Server: Community v3.4.0 (c 3335) schema 4,113
Time:   Oct 18, 2011 8:56:51 PM


Diagnostics:    Inspect Web Script (com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/creado.post)
```

I don't know where is the problem
Somebody can help me?

I did some changes...

avi2flv-transform-context.xml:

```
<entry key="Linux">
        <value>ffmpeg -y -i '${target}' ${flv.encoder.params} '${source}'</value>
</entry>
```

Source <-> Target

```
<props>
    <prop key="flv.encoder.params">-threads 2 -s 320x240 -r 29.97 -threads 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 300 -qmin 3 -b 512k -async 50 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k</prop>
</props>
```

change parameters

error:

```
The Web Script /alfresco/s/gcd/fondo/9fe0bf90-1875-4f51-9f75-7c35f6d0802c has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.

500 Description:    An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Message:    09250001 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 09250004 Failed to execute script '/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/guardar.post.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)': 09250003 Content conversion failed: reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/25/8/27/efff7050-3a67-492d-9e5b-507c03bd0a80.bin, mimetype=video/x-msvideo, size=256362496, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/25/8/28/cb81b7f2-3c72-4266-afd7-0d1a3fb9f420.bin, mimetype=video/x-flv, size=0, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@18c4074f

Exception:  org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException - 09250002 Transformation failed - status indicates an error: Execution result: os: Linux command: [ffmpeg, -y, -i, '/home/inventiaplus/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_target_4598080275234396407.flv', -threads 2 -s 320x240 -r 29.97 -threads 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 300 -qmin 3 -b 512k -async 50 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k, '/home/inventiaplus/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_source_6538382831295915428.avi'] succeeded: false exit code: 1 out: err: FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al. configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1.2 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --e

    ...

Exception:  org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException - 09250003 Content conversion failed: reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/25/8/27/efff7050-3a67-492d-9e5b-507c03bd0a80.bin, mimetype=video/x-msvideo, size=256362496, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/25/8/28/cb81b7f2-3c72-4266-afd7-0d1a3fb9f420.bin, mimetype=video/x-flv, size=0, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@18c4074f

    org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:177)

Exception:  org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException - 09250004 Failed to execute script '/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/guardar.post.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)': 09250003 Content conversion failed: reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/25/8/27/efff7050-3a67-492d-9e5b-507c03bd0a80.bin, mimetype=video/x-msvideo, size=256362496, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/25/8/28/cb81b7f2-3c72-4266-afd7-0d1a3fb9f420.bin, mimetype=video/x-flv, size=0, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@18c4074f

    org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:194)

Exception:  org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 09250001 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 09250004 Failed to execute script '/com/inventiaplus/gcd/fondo/guardar.post.js (in repository store workspace://SpacesStore/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Web Scripts Extensions)': 09250003 Content conversion failed: reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/25/8/27/efff7050-3a67-492d-9e5b-507c03bd0a80.bin, mimetype=video/x-msvideo, size=256362496, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2011/10/25/8/28/cb81b7f2-3c72-4266-afd7-0d1a3fb9f420.bin, mimetype=video/x-flv, size=0, encoding=null, locale=es_ES] options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@18c4074f

    org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:758)

Server: Community v3.4.0 (c 3335) schema 4,113
Time:   Oct 25, 2011 8:28:29 AM
```

I use command line

```
ffmpeg -y -i /home/inventiaplus/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_source_6538382831295915428.avi -threads 2 -s 320x240 -r 29.97 -threads 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 300 -qmin 3 -b 512k -async 50 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 128k /home/inventiaplus/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_target_4598080275234396407.flv
```

and It works

Comment: Did you try with enabling the sample file `video-transformation-context.xml.sample` that ships with Alfresco 4.0, rather than writing your own context file from scratch?

Comment: I try using video-transformation-context.xml but don't work.
Transformer for 'video/x-msvideo' source mime type and 'video/x-flv' target mime type was not found. Operation can't be performed

Comment: You may need to clone one of the entries in there if your source/target type aren't in the standard set, but that'll be a good example to get you started

Answer (score 2):

That error states that the `ffmpeg` command fails:

```
command: [ffmpeg, -i, '/home/inventiaplus/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_target_3008293789769608319.flv', -vcodec flv, '/home/inventiaplus/alfresco/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_source_5021918644492976031.avi'] succeeded: false exit code: 1 [...]
```

Try that command on the command line and look at the error. Besides, from that command line it seems that you were trying to transform a `flv` into a `avi`, but you state you were trying to do the opposite.

Comment: I try in line command, and it works, I change target <-> source, and the problem persists.